# Want printer to pause after printing one page ( to let me reverse )

Tags: 12.10, printing, samsung

I am using Ubuntu 12.10 and have a Samsung SCX3200 series MFP.

**Problem statement**: Suppose I have multiple pages to print but I want to print both sides. To do so, I must print one page at a time and invert the page.

**What I want**: I want to give one single print command for printing more than one pages and printer should wait for me after printing every single page.

I don't know if that is even possible, but thought I should check it out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just feed the printer the sheets one by one, have the rest in hand or kept aside. Feasible?

Comment: @AneeshKarthikC that will do, but I was looking for a more ingenious way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way of doing it would be to print the odd pages first, feed all of them back in, and then print the even pages. It's not quite as concise as a single command, but it would be a lot quicker than authorising every individual page manually.

To do this: in the "Print" menu, go to the "Page Setup" tab. Under the "Layout" column of that page will be a box marked "Only Print". There, choose "Odd sides" and send the print job off - wait for it to finish, invert pages as necessary and then do the same again with "Even sides" (remembering to check the paper tray for the last page afterwards, if your document has an odd number of sides!)

This is the best solution I can think of for emulating duplex printing - it could have some issues if you want to do many-to-one printing, but for one-page-to-one-side it will work fine.

For many-to-one (say, if you want 2 pages to a side), you'd need to put the page sequences in manually - i.e. in Range on the main print page, you would type "1,2,5,6,9,10,..." the first time, followed by "3,4,7,8,..." the second. It's not perfect, but it'd work.

Comment: It will be far better than the earlier way of course. I wish there was some better way... Thank you nonetheless

Comment: @Tatsat I hadn't finished typing, I hate this keyboard sometimes. More info incoming via edit.

Comment: @Tatsat there we go. Accidentally hit tab and then space when typing, so the answer sent way too soon originally. This is the best way I could think of for doing it.

Comment: That is a neat way of doing it. I think I will stick with this solution :) Thank you so much.